# How to use one image for more product?

Tags: product-images, magento-1.9.3.2

Is there any ways to use same image for more products ?

Comment: Are you trying to bulk import images for your products?

Comment: For adding simple product also.

Answer (score 2):

By default Magento has not provided functionality to share same image among multiple products, but by custom module you can get this.

I am not sure whether it will work or not, but you can try this [link](http://www.pixelpaul.net/magento-share-images-on-more-products/.)

You can also try this [extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/setubridge-reuseproductimagesinmedia.html).